# os.path.join with normal joining with os.path.sep on starts path and etc.?

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    path_one = "/hello/world"
    path_two = "/my/little/friend"
    path_tree = 3

    print os.path.join(path_one, path_two, str(path_tree))
    # /my/little/friend\3 , but i want get this /hello/world/my/little/friend/3
    print os.path.join(path_two, str(path_tree))
    # /my/little/friend\3 , but i want get this /my/little/friend/3

    # ok, go

    print os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path_one), os.path.abspath(path_two), str(path_tree))
    # C:\my\little\friend\3 , but i want get C:\hello\world\my\little\friend\3
    print os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path_two), str(path_tree))
    # C:\my\little\friend\3 , all right!
    print os.path.join(os.path.abspath(path_two), str(path_tree), '/', '232\\')
    # /232\ , but i want C:\my\little\friend\3\232\
```

How can normally without dancing with a tambourine join the pieces of the path?

Answer (score 2):

The [`os.path.join()` function documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) specifically states that absolute paths cause preceding paths to be discarded:

> If any component is an absolute path, all previous components (on Windows, including the previous drive letter, if there was one) are thrown away, and joining continues.

You are joining multiple paths that start with `/`. *Remove* the initial path separator from anything but the first path element:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.join('/foo/bar', '/spam/eggs')
'/spam/eggs'
>>> os.path.join('/foo/bar', 'spam/eggs')
'/foo/bar/spam/eggs'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are joining two absolute paths (paths from the root of the file system, i.e., starting with `/`). When you do this, the second one takes precedence; how could it not? Solution: don't do that.